# multi-vectorization via MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I am not sure if I named this problem correctly:

What I have:

```
X = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; 6 2 5 5 4 5 6 3 7 6];
Z = [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0];
```

Now my problem is:

We are comparing the second whole row of matrix X into matrix Z (both have the same number of coulmns but may vary in number of rows)
What I would like to achive is a result below:

```
ans = [5 5 6 7]
```

beacuse:

```
X(2,Z(1,:)) = 5
X(2,Z(2,:)) = 5
X(2,Z(3,:)) = 6
X(2,Z(4,:)) = 7
```

So my problem is I would like to do it wihout any loops, cells or annonymous functions. Just shortening code by vectorize everything. Can I do it in ONE line ??

This above doesn't work if I do as follows:

```
X(2,Z(:,:))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually quite simple - you can just use a matrix multiplication between the second row of `X` and the transpose of `Z`:

```
> X(2,:)*Z'
ans =

   5   5   6   7

>
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution by @Paul R is very nice, here is an alternate way in 2 lines:

```
[myRow, myCol] = find(Z');
X(2,myRow)
```

Comment: With Octave that gives me `5   5   7   6` - does it work in MATLAB ?

Comment: @PaulR Didn't notice the change in order, it should be ok now.

Comment: Yes, that seems to work now - it now gives me `5 5 6 7` in Octave anyway.